# Installing Oracle jdk from webupd8 ppa

Tags: ppa, repository, jdk, oracle, add-apt-repository

Is it still safe and stable to install Oracle jdk via:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`?

Or is it best practice to install Oracle jdk via:

[Official Oracle jdk8 download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **will always be safer to install directly** from those who developed the software in question.

**That being said**, I guarantee ***almost everybody*** that install Oracle's JDK and JRE ***uses this repository*** you mentioned. Became almost like an official repository for Oracle's JDK/JRE.

**Pros:**

- *easier to install*;
- *easier to maintain*;
- *easier to update*;

**Cons:**

- *it isn't official* (but almost like one);

I tend to go with downloading stuff, compiling and installing myself. That way I can keep good track of things the way I like and modify them. This is somewhat what I like to call, in this day and age, the 'lack of gears' somewhere between my brain cells..